# Hamlet html not registering <head> or <title> tags correctly for my home route handler

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

For some reason the `<head>` tag for the home of my website is not being processed the way I would like. Here is the source code of my site that I get from firefox. Please note that the first head and title tags are empty:

```
<html><head><title></title><style>form{margin:0 auto;width:250px}</style></head><body><head><title>Fishing Weather Hub </title>
<meta name="description" content="Completely free fishing weather data provided by NOAA and Open Weather Maps. Designed to be simple and easy to use.">
<meta name="keywords" content="fishing weather,fishing,weather">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
</head>
<header><center style="font-size:30px">Fishing Weather Hub</center>
...
```

Here is the Haskell code for this route handler. To me I have made it clear that within the head tag I would like to specify the title and meta tags. The HTML above does not seem to align with this code.

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html    
getHomeR = do

  clearSession

  key <- liftIO $ MYP.randomString 9

  setSession "cache_key" (T.pack key) 

  sess <- getSession

  -- Generate the location form
  (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost $ renderDivs locationForm

  defaultLayout $ do
    [whamlet|
<head>
  <title>Fishing Weather Hub 
  <meta name="description" content="Completely free fishing weather data provided by NOAA and Open Weather Maps. Designed to be simple and easy to use.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="fishing weather,fishing,weather">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<header>
  <center style="font-size:30px">Fishing Weather Hub
  <br>
  <form method=post action=@{ProcessLocationFormR} enctype=#{enctype}>
    ^{widget}
    <button>Submit
  <a href="https://www.anglerwise.com/2010/02/09/how-does-barometric-pressure-affect-fishing/">How does barometric pressure affect fishing?
|]
    --CSS
    toWidget
      [lucius|
form {
margin: 0 auto;
width:250px;
}
|]
```

I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just drop HTML from `whamlet` directly in `defaultLayout`, it goes in `toWidget` and so in the `<body>`. For the title in particular, use [`setTitle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.18.7/docs/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v:setTitle) to set it. For the rest of the stuff that goes in `<head>` (like your meta tags), wrap their `hamlet` quasi-quotes in [`toWidgetHead`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.18.7/docs/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#v:toWidgetHead).